# Car battery appears good but car won't start

Tags: battery, starting, nissan, power

My 2005 Nissan won't start today. Battery is relatively new(about one year old) and I can turn the lights on, front headlights, and it appears fine.
However, when I tried to start the car by turning the car key, suddenly all the power is gone.

If I play with the battery connection a little bit, the power will be back. And everything works fine, headlight, radio etc and stay strong. But if i tried to start the engine again, the power will immediately gone.

I tried search the web but can't find a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tighten the connections at the battery.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the terminals to the battery.  clean the battery and terminals with a wire brush or a battery post cleaning tool.  Reinstall.  If you have posts, you may need to replace the clamp if the current one is too stretched.  Also check your ground is good and connected to a clean part of the body or block.

Comment: you could also check the state of the wiring to the clamp, could be a weak connection there...

Comment: If all the connections are good you may just have a blown fusible link... Same symptoms

Comment: Check on the connection point that's kind of square shaped... There should be a thin wire... Is it fried or broken? Even dirty can cause it to ground out.

Answer (score 2):

This exact same issue happened with me in a Ford Focus. As rpmerf said, check the terminals.

In my case, after removing the terminals from the battery and reseating them, the car cranked over fine.